# Find if lines intersect, only knowing gradient.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Is it possible to find out if and where two lines intersect with only knowing the gradient of said lines?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes just look whether they are not paralel or skew , i,e , cross product is not zero.

Comment: I'm sorry, read edit.

Comment: not possible bacause there would be infinitely many lines which have same gradient @fredthadinosaur

Answer (score 0):

If you don't take the overlap case into consideration, then they intersect if and only if their gradients are different

Comment: Correction, Read Edit.

Comment: If you have to know where they intersect it's not possible. @fredthadinosaur

Comment: Oh, Would you mind explaining why? @Vim